# Code Dynamically Run from textbox in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, textbox, runtime

I run dynamically code from a TextBox in vb.net. Only one TextBox txtoutput can be accessed in dynamically run code.

While I get the input from another TextBox, the compiler shows the following error:

> 'txtbox1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

How can I resolve this error?

```vb
Dim input = TextBox3.Text

' Create "code" literal to pass to the compiler.  
'  
' Notice the <% = input % > where the code read from the text file (Code.txt)   
' is inserted into the code fragment.  

Dim code = <code>  
               Imports System  
               Imports System.Windows.Forms  

               Public Class TempClass  

                   Public Sub UpdateText(ByVal txtOutput    As TextBox)  
                       <%= input %>  
                   End Sub

               End Class 

           </code>

' Create the VB.NET compiler.  
Dim vbProv = New VBCodeProvider()
' Create parameters to pass to the compiler.  
Dim vbParams = New CompilerParameters()
' Add referenced assemblies.  
vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll")
vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
vbParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
vbParams.GenerateExecutable = False
' Ensure we generate an assembly in memory and not as a physical file.  
vbParams.GenerateInMemory = True

' Compile the code and get the compiler results (contains errors, etc.)  
Dim compResults = vbProv.CompileAssemblyFromSource(vbParams, code.Value)

' Check for compile errors  
If compResults.Errors.Count > 0 Then

    ' Show each error.  
    For Each er In compResults.Errors
        MessageBox.Show(er.ToString())
    Next

Else

    ' Create instance of the temporary compiled class.  
    Dim obj As Object = compResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("TempClass")
    ' An array of object that represent the arguments to be passed to our method (UpdateText).  
    Dim args() As Object = {Me.txtoutput}
    ' Execute the method by passing the method name and arguments.  
    Dim t As Type = obj.GetType().InvokeMember("UpdateText", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, obj, args)

End If
```

Comment: For reference, the code was copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264196/832052) (or perhaps the original [blog post](http://vbcity.com/blogs/jatkinson/archive/2010/04/24/dynamically-read-compile-and-run-source-code-from-a-text-file.aspx#691956)) and one line was changed `Dim input = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Code.txt")` >>> `Dim input = TextBox3.Text`. You expect that you can read from a TextBox instead of a file, which is reasonable. Can you edit your question to add the contents of TextBox3 at runtime?

Comment: Your code works if you put this in TextBox3 for example: `MessageBox.Show("Hello world.")` so the content of the TextBox is critically important.

Comment: You may want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487929/832052

Comment: thanks i will try and check